# Showing the user that an XPage View is loading

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am building an application that has very large documents, and many documents in the views.  In my testing environment, these views take a view seconds to load, but for the customer, these views (shown in the dynamicViewPanel) are taking upwards of 12 seconds (or up to a minute the first time it is being loaded on a given day) to load.  No update is made on the browser until add data becomes available. My question is not about performance however.

How can I go about immediately loading the xpage so that the user sees "something is happening and the browser did not swallow my request", yet load the view when the data eventually becomes available while using the dynamic view panel control?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding partial refreshs Fredrik Norling made a neat control called "Standby Custom Control" that displays a "wait" icon when partial refreshs happen. Not sure if it will work when loading the whole page though...
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control

Comment: This is amazing for many cases that are being a pain currently, and I will definitely keep it in, Thanks!  Unfortunately, it does not seem to be a good choice for my main problem area, initial loading of the XPage when (possibly) the indexes of the views still need to be built. Am I missing something that the tool can do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dojo modules there is a simple way to implement such a stand by for Partial Update and for opening new pages.

I found it [in a blog by Vikas Tiwari](http://xpagesera.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-ajax-loading-control-in-xpages-for.html)

This is a two step process:

1. Add following Dojo modules to your XPage.

> < xp:this.resources>
>
> < xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib">< /xp:dojoModule>
>
> < xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading">< /xp:dojoModule>
>
> < /xp:this.resources>

2. Add following lines to the EventHandler of your button/link which is going to be used for Partial Update:

> < xp:this.onStart>< /xp:this.onStart>
>
> < xp:this.onComplete>< /xp:this.onComplete>
>
> < xp:this.onError>< /xp:this.onError>

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but you could try my ViewGrid plugin from here [OpenNTF ViewGrid](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20ViewGrid). If the view indexes are being build, the control 'waits' until that process is done (with a loading indicator)